# listview swipe to delete not update after swiping in android

Tags: android, sqlite, swipe

i am using listview swipe to delete.it is from the sqlite database.when swiping its delete from the database but still in the listview not getting update, it will update only when i refresh the activity.here is my code below.

MainActivity.java

```
  SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                    notificationList,
                    new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {

                                final DesignItems m = designItemsList.get(position);
                                DesignItems designItems = new DesignItems();

                                designItems.setNotificationId(m.getNotificationId());
                                dbHelper.deleteInterestId(designItems);

                                list_adapter.remove(position);

                                list_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }

                        }
                    });
    notificationList.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

i have declared remove method in notification adapter. below is my code.

NotificationAdapter.java

```
public void remove(int position) {

    Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    designItemsList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

i dont know, where i made a mistake.i hope if any better solution.it will very helpful for me.

Comment: did you try notifyItemRemoved(position); ?

Comment: bro,u mean in adapter or main activity?

Comment: either on adapter or activity...it might work..check it...not pretty sure...

Comment: its not showing bro..@AmitJangid

Comment: why arent you using std components like: `ItemTouchHelper` and `RecyclerView` and `PagedListAdapter`? your live would be 5 times easier then...

Comment: Can you add the line 'notifyItemRemoved(position)' in remove method and try

Comment: i have tried but not showing notifyItemRemoved @SaiPrasad

Comment: when i swipe listview data ..it removed from database but not in listview .. it update only when i refresh the activity..i am using base adapter.. @pskink

Comment: when i swipe, it come back in listview but its removed from database..

Comment: @JameelAhamed, please write the code of binding the adapter with list

Comment: but i need same position .. if i write code of binding adapter, it moves to top after every delete action..this also i have tried bro..                   designItemsList = dbHelper.getAllNotification();

//                                    list_adapter = new NotificationAdapter(
//                                            NotificationListView.this, designItemsList);  
       notificationList.setAdapter(list_adapter); @NiravBhavsar